# Add result to html anchor to create a link to result in javascript

Tags: javascript

The result.text contains a link ... eg: http://www.somesite.com/

I currently have some text that is being populated inside a

tag.

Here is the code:

JS:

```
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = result.text;
```

HTML:

`<a href="" id="info"></p`>

What I need to do is populate an anchor instead so I can link to it (create a working link).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating and attaching nodes can be unnecessarily costly. You can change the href value by setting its attribute:

```
document.getElementById('info').setAttribute('href',result.text);
```

Works in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
document.getElementById("info").href = result.text;
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = result.text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an anchor and append it

```
var anchor  = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = result.text;

document.getElementById("info").appendChild(anchor);
```

or if `#info` is an anchor

```
document.getElementById("info").href = result.text;
```